# GZip compression in OpenZFS

Tags: gzip, zlib, kernel-module, zfs

In OpenZFS source code, since gzip.c is located in zfs/module/zfs, is there a Zlib kernel module for ZFS? Can ZFS link with regular Zlib library to do GZIP compression?

Answer (score 0):

Which platform do you care about? For Linux, you can see where this happens in the SPL in [`spl-zlib.c`](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/spl/blob/master/module/spl/spl-zlib.c). It includes `linux/zlib_compat.h`, which is a [wrapper](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/spl/blob/master/include/linux/zlib_compat.h) around the `kernel/zlib.h` implementation in the Linux kernel.